# Nextjs Routing works in everything except for Google Chrome

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a very strange problem. I have a little website I have that I developed in nextJS which works fine in every browser except for Chrome. The pushing of a query part of it works, but the pathname part doesn't work and the browser doesn't re-direct. Here's my code:

```
import Nav from "../components/nav";
import Router, { useRouter } from "next/router";
import {useState} from 'react';

export default function SimpleSearch({ cities }) {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { query } = router;

  const [city, setSelect] = useState('All');

  const handleChange = (e) => {
      setSelect(e.target.value)
  }

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    Router.push(
      {
        pathname: "/camps",
        query: {city, page: 1 },
      })
  };

  return (
    <section
      className="hero is-info is-fullheight"
      style={{
        backgroundImage: "url('/cover2.jpg')",
        backgroundSize: "cover",
      }}
    >
      <div className="hero-head">
        <Nav />
      </div>
      <div className="hero-body">
        <div className="container has-text-centered">
          <p className="title has-text-info is-size-1 has-text-weight-light">
            Where is your next adventure?
          </p>
          <div className="columns is-centered">
            <div className="column is-3">
              <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <div className="field has-addons">
                  <div className="control is-expanded">
                    <div className="select is-fullwidth">
                      <select className="input is-rounded" name="city" onChange={handleChange}>
                        <option value="all">All</option>
                        {cities.nodes.map((town) => {
                          return (
                            <option
                              key={town.acfDetails.city}
                              value={town.acfDetails.city}
                            >
                              {town.acfDetails.city}
                            </option>
                          );
                        })}
                      </select>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="control">
                    <button
                      type="submit"
                      className="button is-info"
                    >
                      Bon Voyage
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}
```

I'm figuring it's some kind of weird thing and hoping one of you can help out. Thank you so much!

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean that the query string works but the pathname doesn't? Can you also clarify where you are attempting to redirect?

Comment: So when I hit "Bon voyage" I get this in the url:

http://localhost:3000/?city=all

But the page just reloads the same page, instead of pushing to /camps?city=all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, classic form `onSubmit` issue. You need to prevent the default form action. Without this the form submission reloads the current page.

```
const handleSubmit = (event) => { // <-- consume onSubmit event object
  event.preventDefault(); // <-- prevent default form action
  Router.push(
    {
      pathname: "/camps",
      query: {city, page: 1 },
    })
};
```

Comment: You are a saint!!! Weird how its only Chrome that does that. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @sylargaf True, I'd expect default form actions to be fairly standard across the board as this behavior predates many web technologies used currently.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a mistake in your way of calling the router.

It should be `router`, not `Router`, because you declared the `useRouter()` as `router`.

Also, when you call the `handleSubmit` function, just instantly return the `router.push(...)` function. No need to wrap it in curly braces.

Comment: Thank you for the help and suggestion. That didn't solve it :(. But I did tidy up handleSubmit!

Comment: Wait a minute. Have you tried to call `e.preventDefault` in your submit function? It is required to prevent reloading when sending a form.